# Writing conditional expressions in offset attribute of logic:iterate tag for struts 1.3

Tags: struts

I want to write a condition in the offset attribute of logic:iterate tag in struts1.3. My tag looks like this

logic:iterate name="instlist" id="inst" type="com.umonitor.fundstransfer.beans.FtInstitution"  indexId="counter"

I want to set the offset value to every 8th element in the list.

Is that possible? I wanted to implement paging but the problem is I cant change the action class or add any but only manipulate the values in the jsp. I have the complete list in the jsp and have to display 8 rows only in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the 'offset' and 'length' attributes of logic:iterate? http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/logic/iterate.html

These attributes will enable you to start at a certain position (offset) and then show only the next 8 entries (length).

In your case I guess you have a parameter called something like 'page' and you'll need to set the offset to page*8 and the length to 8.

Comment: There is a problem to this, the list i use in the iterator has size 30 so when i set length and offset it shows the first 8 of that list and skips the rest. is there a way to add buttons to the iterate tag like  prev and next